# cocos2dJs multiline label

Tags: javascript, html, cocos2d-iphone

do you know if there is a way to create multiline text in cocos2d-js in the new version 0.2?

I've been trying some things but none worked

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's supported in cocos2d-html5, check it out:

Github repo: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-html5
Site: http://cocos2d-x.org/

Answer (score 1):

It's not in cocos2d-iphone, I'd be surprised if any other cocos2d version supports it.

One workaround is to split your string and use multiple labels to display each line.